# Calendar v3 no sample for webapplication

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm working with Asp.net C#

I want to retreive Events list, I have a valid `token` from oAuth2.
How can I initialize service with this token?

```
Events results = service.Events.List().Fetch();
```

Please doen't send me Native Application Sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google-Api-Dot-Net-Client has an [ASP.Net Sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg/Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2) this sample uses the Task API, but the authentication piece should be identical. If you go to the [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted) page there is a link download all the samples and you should be able to play with the Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2 sample.